# Missing data with high correlation - binary feature

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data

I have a dataset that has a binary feature with 100% correlation to the labels, but it also has a lot of missing values (around 84% of samples don't have this value).
I don't really know how to approach this problem.

I've tried treating this feature as a categorical feature and split it into two dummy variables and got fairly good results. I also tried setting all zeros to -1, all null values to 0 and all ones to 1 and got even better results, but this damaged the high correlation and reduced it from 100% to around 24%.

My current approach is to use KNNImputer and remove the missing data this way, but this process takes a long time because of all the missing data.

What are the options when handling binary features with extremely high correlation that have a lot of missing values?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is currently not very clear what you are trying to accomplish. Build a predictive model? If so, I am confused why you would want that for examples that contain a feature with perfect correlation. Without trying to be mean, wouldn't a simple `if ... else ...` do that job just fine already?

Comment: I am trying to build a predictive model. What you're suggesting would work perfectly if this feature didn't have missing values. Unfortunately, most samples don't specify a value for this feature, so I'm not sure how to handle it...

Comment: `if (has_awesome_feature(example)) { return model1(example.awesome_feature)} else {return model2(example.all_other_features)}`. Essentially you split your dataset into examples that have a value for `awesome_feature` and those that do not have it. For examples that have `awesome_feature`, classification is trivial, for the others you build a model that doesn't use `awesome_feature`.

Comment: Oh now I got it. Thanks!